# Is there a rule or policy about collusion in moderator elections?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators, policy

Christianity.SE is having a mod election, and someone suggested colluding to ensure that the 4 pro-tem mods get elected:

[WITHDRAWN: How can those with a "current mods" preference ensure *all* mods get elected?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2049/how-can-those-with-a-current-mods-preference-ensure-all-mods-get-elected)

I agree that the 4 pro-tems have done an excellent job and I'd also like to see them all elected.  But it seems contrary to the whole idea of elections (and somewhat offensive) to have someone try to coordinate voting to ensure that certain candidates get elected, so I was wondering if there's actually any rule or policy about this.

Comment: Is Affable Geek a current moderator?  Unless he is, I don't see how you can call this collusion.  It looks to me more like a "get out the vote" effort, which is a perfectly acceptable form of political activity. Regular elections do this sort of thing all the time.  Note that the anti-establishment folks are perfectly within their rights to do some campaigning of their own.

Comment: If you read the answer he gave to his question, he suggests "UserNames starting A - F vote for Caleb, Elendia, Mason - Not for Wax, UserNames starting G - N vote for Elendia, Wax, Caleb - Not for Mason..." I know that "get out the vote" efforts often imply "...and vote for our candidates" but this seems to be only telling people "if you vote, you should vote as follows:"

Comment: "Strategic voting" is not a new thing either.  You pick the voting system that you think is best (in our case STV), and hope that it's good enough to get gamed as little as possible.  But the principle of "people can use their votes however they wish" is just as valid during moderator elections as it is when voting on posts, if not more so.

Comment: I've got no problem with people using their own votes however they wish (I do!), but I labelled it collusion because he's telling other people how to use their votes.

Comment: Unless you can demonstrate a weakness in STV that gives an unfair advantage to a particular candidate, I don't see what else you can do, beyond making the case that political activity is possibly beyond the scope of your Meta site.  Voters still gets to decide for themselves how to use their votes.

Comment: I don't think any proponent of STV that understands math would even consider implementing it in a way that gives people fewer votes than there are positions to be filled. SE's implementation can be mathematically proven to fail to meet STV's goals of electing the people with the broadest support. (IMHO this completely justifies collusion among the bloc of voters who favor any 4 specific candidates).

Comment: @Wooble: In other words, because you think the system is broken, the end justifies the means.  Wars have been started over less.

Comment: "But it seems contrary to the whole idea of elections (and somewhat offensive) to have someone try to coordinate voting to ensure that certain candidates get elected". Er. What elections have you been watching? Political parties exist to coordinate voting to ensure certain candidates get elected

Answer (score 4):

You're free to make voting recommendations on the site, as long as you don't spam them in inappropriate places. For example, asking people to vote for specific candidates on the main site would be inappropriate. I would see this as a simple recommendation on who to vote for, and other users are free to follow the recommendation or ignore it.

I would also consider this post to be off-topic on the meta site and think it should be closed. This would apply to every post that is primarily meant to recommend specific candidates. But the content itself would be appropriate e.g. in chat or as a comment on nominations or election posts.

Comment: Please be clearer about "spam them in inappropriate places."

Comment: @RobertHarvey I clarified it a bit, I mainly meant campaigning on the main site for specific candidates.

Comment: Why would this be off-topic on the site meta? Because it doesn't seek input and discussion from the community? I certainly think it could posed so that it does... Then would it be acceptable?